# Remove gameobject with trigger

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, triggers

I want to disable a plane when the camera enters the sphere but can't seem to get it to work. I know the panel1.SetActive(true) works, as I have tried and set it to false, thus making the plane disappear, but I can't seem to get the panel1.SetActive(false) to work. I have made the null object that contains the camera, and is the object being animated to be a trigger. images below.

[the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBtgL.png)

[the gameobject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8PyL.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "camera enters the sphere"? You want to move camera object inside sphere? Or you want to check if sphere is visible?

Comment: simply add "Debug.Log("test");" throughout your code and you will find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be that there is nothing colliding with your trigger. The GameObject you try to move into the trigger needs a Collider aswell, if its still the default Camera there is no component attached which knows about how to collide.

Comment: hmm, I have added a box collider to the null object containing the camera, and made it a trigger as well. The null object i the object i move into the sphere but still nothing happens.

Comment: why did you make it a trigger? a trigger usually is something static other colliders move into, thats not what you want. also if you move a collider a lot you should attach a rigidbody aswell (if you dont want the physics that come with it, set it to kinematic) http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html especially the part at the end where it shows what collides with what.

Comment: actually you need the rigidbody, a static collider doesnt collide with a static trigger collider.